# org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query in spring boot and Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When I am trying to implement the JPQL query, I am getting the following error,

```
{
"message": "could not execute query; SQL [select alerts0_.nalert_id as nalert_i1_0_, alerts0_.bis_active as bis_acti2_0_, alerts0_.dalert_date as dalert_d3_0_, alerts0_.ndept_to as ndept_to4_0_, alerts0_.ninst_to as ninst_to5_0_, alerts0_.nreceiver_id as nreceive6_0_, alerts0_.nsender_id as nsender_7_0_, alerts0_.nsubdept_to as nsubdept8_0_, alerts0_.salert_action_data as salert_a9_0_, alerts0_.salert_desc as salert_10_0_, alerts0_.salert_subject as salert_11_0_, alerts0_.salert_type as salert_12_0_ from alerts alerts0_ where alerts0_.ninst_to=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query",
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"path": "/spacestudy/rockefeller/control/alerts/getAlertDetails"
}
```

And my repository query is like the following,

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Alerts a")
public List<Alerts> findByAlertType();
```

When I hard-coded Query like `@Query("SELECT a FROM Alerts a WHERE a.nreceiverId = 649")`, then also getting the same error.

And I am calling this query in my service like the following:

```
alert= alertsRepositoryObj.findByAlertType();
```

And my model class Alerts.java like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="alerts")
public class Alerts implements Serializable
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "alerts_seq_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "alerts_seq_generator", sequenceName = "alerts_seq",allocationSize=1)
@Column(name="nalert_id",columnDefinition="serial")
public Integer nalertId;

@Column(name="salert_desc")
public String salertDesc;

@NotNull
@Column(name="nsender_id")
public Integer nsenderId;

@Column(name="dalert_date")
public LocalDate dalertDate;

@Column(name="salert_subject")
public String salertSubject;

@Column(name="salert_action_data")
public String salertActionData;

@Column(name="salert_type")
public String salertType;

@Column(name="ninst_to")
public Integer ninstTo;

@Column(name="ndept_to")
public Integer nDeptTo;

@Column(name="nsubdept_to")
public Integer nsubdeptTo;

@Column(name="nreceiver_id")
public Integer nreceiverId;

@NotNull
@Column(name="bis_active")
public Boolean bisActive=true;

@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "salert_action_data", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public RoomTransfer roomTransfer;   

public Integer getNalertId() 
{
    return nalertId;
}

public void setNalertId(Integer nalertId)
{
    this.nalertId = nalertId;
}

public String getSalertDesc() 
{
    return salertDesc;
}

public void setSalertDesc(String salertDesc)
{
    this.salertDesc = salertDesc;
}

public Integer getNsenderId()
{
    return nsenderId;
}

public void setNsenderId(Integer nsenderId)
{
    this.nsenderId = nsenderId;
}

public LocalDate getDalertDate() 
{
    return dalertDate;
}

public void setDalertDate(LocalDate dalertDate)
{
    this.dalertDate = dalertDate;
}

public String getSalertSubject()
{
    return salertSubject;
}

public void setSalertSubject(String salertSubject) 
{
    this.salertSubject = salertSubject;
}

public String getSalertActionData()
{
    return salertActionData;
}

public void setSalertActionData(String salertActionData)
{
    this.salertActionData = salertActionData;
}

public String getSalertType()
{
    return salertType;
}

public void setSalertType(String salertType) 
{
    this.salertType = salertType;
}

public Integer getNinstTo() 
{
    return ninstTo;
}

public void setNinstTo(Integer ninstTo)
{
    this.ninstTo = ninstTo;
}

public Integer getnDeptTo()
{
    return nDeptTo;
}

public void setnDeptTo(Integer nDeptTo) 
{
    this.nDeptTo = nDeptTo;
}

public Integer getNsubdeptTo()
{
    return nsubdeptTo;
}

public void setNsubdeptTo(Integer nsubdeptTo)
{
    this.nsubdeptTo = nsubdeptTo;
}

public Integer getNreceiverId() 
{
    return nreceiverId;
}

public void setNreceiverId(Integer nreceiverId)
{
    this.nreceiverId = nreceiverId;
}

public Boolean getBisActive()
{
    return bisActive;
}

public void setBisActive(Boolean bisActive)
{
    this.bisActive = bisActive;
}   

public RoomTransfer getRoomTransfer()
{
    return roomTransfer;
}

public void setRoomTransfer(RoomTransfer roomTransfer) 
{
    this.roomTransfer = roomTransfer;
}

public Alerts() 
{
    super();
}       
}
```

Why this error happening? Since this is a simple JPQL query. How can I trouble shoot the exact error here?

Comment: Strangely there is where clause `where alerts0_.ninst_to=?` while there is none in your JPQL. Can you check the following 1. Show your entire repo interface. 2. Does findAll work. It is equivalent to your query. 3. Check annotations. Query from spring data, correct? 4. Methods with `by` word are special in spring data and generate where clause. @Query should have higher priority (see 3), but check if renaming helps.

Comment: I do not find any alertType attribute in your entity, I can see salertType

Comment: Okay, name doesn't matter when we define the query.Learnt that now :)

Comment: do you have any stacktraces which indicate why this query could not be executed?